# Finding the mode of an array

Tags: ruby

So I'm working through the Mean Median and Mode chapter of the Ruby Cookbook, and I'm trying to figure out why the code is doing what it is doing. I get everything else, but what's with adding to the variable modes and then (from the looks of it) reassigning it? I know what all the operators in the code blocks mean but I can't grasp the logic behind it.

```
def modes(array, find_all  = true)
  histogram = array.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h,n| h[n] += 1; h  }
  modes = nil 

  histogram.each_pair do |item, times| 
    modes << item if modes && times == modes[0] and find_all
    modes = [times, item] if (!modes && times >1) or (modes && times > modes[0])
  end

  return modes ? modes[1...modes.size] : modes
end
```

Comment: Is this really the code that was published in the book?

Comment: Yeah it is. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: No wonder. It's a great example of (in my opinion) pretty horrible code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, **do not look at this code as something to emulate**. It has so many problems and is so brittle that I frankly cannot believe it was published.

Here are the major problems:

1. `modes` is the name of the method **and** the name of a temporary variable inside the method
2. The internal `modes` is sometimes nil and sometimes an array, and the behavior of **each line** in the `each_pair` block changes depending on which is which.
3. The first value of the `modes` array is used to store another temporary variable
4. The rest of the values of the `modes` array is used as a return value.
5. The final return statement checks *again* is `modes` is `nil`, returns the tail if not, and returns `nil` if so. Returning `nil` from a method is, as a rule, **not** a good idea. It's liable to break your other code in so many other places and will make you have to perform all of these nil checks everywhere— in short, it will make the rest of the program look like this wretched method.
6. It uses the control flow operators `and` and `or` in place of the boolean operators `&&` and `||` for boolean conditionals

As for your question, I believe the confusion arises from these four lines:

```
histogram.each_pair do |item, times| 
  modes << item if modes && times == modes[0] and find_all
  modes = [times, item] if (!modes && times >1) or (modes && times > modes[0])
end
```

This loops through each pair of the `histogram` hash as follows:

1. Does `modes` exist? And does `times` equal the first element? And should I `find_all`?

   - if so, tack the current `item` onto the end of the array.
   - otherwise, do nothing
2. Is one of the following true?

   - `modes` is `nil` and the `item` was found more than once
   - `modes` is NOT `nil` and the current value of `times` is larger than its first element
   - if so, replace the current value of `modes` with `[times, item]`.
   - otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, that is exactly what I was looking for. I'm not exactly an expert on Ruby but that was, by a measure, more complicated than most of the other solutions I'd seen, so I wanted to know exactly what it was doing. I'll try my hardest not to emulate it in the future!

Comment: Good explanation, Zack. I only skimmed the question before reading your answer.  When I got to `find_all` in your answer I assumed it was `Enumerable#find_all` (which returns an enumerator when no block is passes), but that made *no sense at all*. Just one more problem with the code: giving a variable the name of a built-in method.  Ugh!

Comment: @OceansOnPluto, if you're interested in learning more about how to craft well-reasoned and reliable code, I'd like to recommend you read [Confident Ruby by Avdi Grimm](http://www.confidentruby.com/).